# How to delete a list of files and folder generated via find in terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder, file, macos

I'm generating a list of files and folder that meet certain criteria with use of a command:

```
find ~/ -iname "whatIwantToRemove"
```

The command will generate some results:

```
/Users/me//.Trash/whatIwantToRemove
...
```

I would like to be able to automatically delete all of those files.

---

## Possible solution

I'm looking at [a similar discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1013) on Unix and Linux and was wondering whether the command would work:

```
find . -type f -regex '/ex/' -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with the `-delete` flag?

```
find ~/ -iname "whatIwantToRemove" -delete
```

Comment: Nothing, just my reflex to Google things first. Actually: `sudo find your-directory/ -name 'mytrash' -delete` seems to work

Comment: I used this with a bunch of file copies I had that all had "whatever (1).jpg", "whatever (2).jpg" etc. filenames. I riffed on your command to get an idea of the files to be deleted:
`find . -iname "*(*)*" | wc -l`
Then I deleted with your command.
`find . -iname "*(*)*" -delete`
Thanks!

Comment: `find *.mp4 -delete` command in terminal in the mac worked for me. Thanks Brennon Bortz :)